# Could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB error

Tags: android

I am getting error:

```
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

What is the relationship between Android project version that I created and the Emulator version?

There are so many questions here in but all do not give proper solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator now supports OpenGL. you can set following property while creating your avd.

```
GPU emulation=> yes
```

You can also try set  RAM size to 512 Mb. Hope it will work with you.

Is your app requires OpenGL 2.0? if yest then see
http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html

Let me know whether your problem will solve or not?